# snowflake Copy Into parallel Parquet File load

Tags: parallel-processing, load, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

How can I One time load 5years Parquet data with COPY INTO in a table ? because 1 Month load tooks me 1.5Hours , 5Years will take me 90Hours. if there a possiblity to parallel Load ? and how can i do it ?

The code is for 1Month

```
COPY INTO "PUBLIC"."MYTABLE" ("One_Month_Transactions") FROM SELECT ($1:"One_Month_Transactions" @my_azure_stage/data201601);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the number of files that you have (hopefully, they are in many, many files) and size your warehouse to load them all in a single COPY INTO statement.  Assuming you dedicate a warehouse for a single COPY INTO statement, it'll be able to load 8 files in parallel per node.  1 node is an XS, 2 is a S, 4 is a Medium, and doubles from there.

If you provide a number of files per 1 month, what size warehouse you used, then I could help more accurately size things for you, but the key is doing it all in 1 COPY INTO statement...and do math on 8 files/node * # of nodes per size.

Comment: Thanks !! there is 60 files in 4 Years, so there is  size hase to be XS. I'm doing one this on Test data for 1Year ==> 12files  // 1 Month ==> 1 file . the idea is to try to load 1Year together in a table so 12files !

Comment: A LARGE warehouse will load 64 files in parallel.  As a note, if my answer has provided you assistance, it is good practice to mark it as the correct answer and/or uptick it.  Thank you.

Comment: @MikeWalton Thanks,could you please tell where i can find 8 files per node information.